# Сочинительная или подчинительная связь в предложении?

Tags: запятые

*Всё, что было в жизни, дорого и мило.*

Comment: А разве это у вас предложение?

Comment: Я правильно понял вас, Ольга, поставив запятую?

Comment: А какое средство связи здесь - сочинительный союз, подчинительный союз или союзное слово? Чем является ЧТО? От этого и зависит вид связи.

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, подчинительная.

В любом случае:
*Всё, что было в жизни дорого и мило...

Всё, что было в жизни, дорого и мило.*

Слово "что" всегда указывает именно на подчинительную связь. Можно поставить вопрос от слова "всё": *что именно?* При сочинительной связи вопрос нельзя поставить.